# View background with dynamic multi colors and corners

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view, shapes

I am trying to make a view with dynamic percent tag to set different colors in view and with corners (as figure).

[image]

If only set multi colors is very easy to do that, just calculate percent with view's width and set color to finish that. But I have no idea how to do that with corner.

Is there any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT**

I use ShapeDrawable solution and there is the result as below.
I only update the color and percent tag.

What my question is : why the split line is askew?

[image]

**UPDATE**

There is succesw to get result, but this is not what I want..

[image]

I hope I can get clear split like below:

[image]

Comment: I have found some solution like this: https://azzits.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/customseekbar/

But I that is not what I want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I achived what you expected. Unfortunately, such drawable cannot be made as .xml but can be done in code. Here is the template:

```
ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory sf = new ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory() {
    @Override
    public Shader resize(int width, int height) {
        LinearGradient lg = new LinearGradient(0, 0, width, 0,
                    new int[]{
                            ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.holo_green_light),
                            ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.holo_green_light),
                            ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.holo_orange_light),
                            ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.holo_orange_light),
                            ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.holo_red_light),
                            ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.holo_red_light),
                            ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.holo_purple),
                            ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.holo_purple)},
                    new float[]{0, 0.60f, 0.60f, 0.80f, 0.80f, 0.85f, 0.85f, 1}, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
            return lg;
    }
};
PaintDrawable p = new PaintDrawable();
p.setShape(new RectShape());
p.setCornerRadius(40);
p.setShaderFactory(sf);
```

Look into couple of details above. When creating LinearGradient you have to pass an array of colors and their position inside gradient. In order to achieve `very long` green you have to double green color and pass positions `0` and `0.96f`. Then add `orange` color one time. Be caferul, that the different between `green` and purple must be very low (but the must be a space for `orange` color).

Then just set appropriate radius:

```
p.setCornerRadius(40);
```

This solution is scalable as colors and colors' positions can be dynamically changed.

Comment: Nice, almost there. If you adjust this solution to accept an array of colors or a dictionary of colors with percentage rates, then it would be scalable and instantly reusable to the OP. It should only require tweaking the parameter types and adding a loop. Good job so far.

Comment: Hi, @R.zagorski, I'm vary thankful your answer. I've tried to use your solution to fix my issue. but the result on my edit question.. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: The fourth parameter of `LinearGradient` constructor should be different. Edited the answer.

Comment: I'm so thankful that you continue to reply me.. but the result is not what I want.. I hope I can get something clear split colors. do you have any ideas?

Comment: Modified my answer. To get clear split the beginning position of next gradient color must end on previous color position.

Comment: Thanks for your patient.. its work now! many thankful.